# Suggestions for Adsense in messaging application

Tags: ads, adsense

I am developing a small social network, which is probably going to get a lot of users. It will be based mainly on private messaging between customers. I am willing to display content specific ads (just like Gmail does), which is based on the content in the messages.

I have developed algorithm to extract the key words in order to use them for Adsense. But since this is private information I can not just make it available for the public (the crawler). Not only it is impossible to specify a login for the crawler to EVERY customer's inbox, but it is also not correct to expose their private information in such way.

Can you suggest me a clever way to do this? Is this even possible? Is it possible through other ad services?